# Why probability is more then 1 when SD is less then 1?

Tags: scipy, gaussian

```
stats.norm(0, 0.1).pdf(0) -> 3.9894
```

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))

mu = 0
variance = (0.5*0.5) / np.sqrt(100)
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))

plt.show()
```

Comment: solution to find probability: 
scipy.stats.norm(mu, sigma).cdf(Point1) - scipy.stats.norm(mu, sigma).cdf(Point2)

Comment: Future readers of your proposed "solution" should know that this computes the *cumulative* probability up to the given point, i.e. the probability that the underlying random variable takes any value *less than* the given point. That's not "the probability".

Comment: I was expecting that my 'solution' gives the probability between 2 points (integral). For example, it can answer the question: what is prob to get a point between 0 and 1. Am I right?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I did not see your minus sign. Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [probability *density* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)'s pointwise value is not a probability, so there is no reason to expect its value to be less than 1.

Probabilities are expressed by appropriate *integrals* of PDFs. For example, a function that takes the value 10 between 0 and 1/10, and the value 0 everywhere else, is a valid PDF. Its value at 1/20 is 10>1, but its integral over any interval [a,b] is ≤1. It is this integral that expresses a probability, namely that the probability of the underlying random variable taking a value between a and b.